# Why does Jetty's cross-origin filter cause the server to crash?

Tags: jetty, same-origin-policy

As instructed in http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html, to enable cross-origin requests on jetty-8.1.18.v20150929 (bundled with BaseX 8.5), I downloaded `jetty-servlets-8.1.18.v20150929.jar`, and placed it in WEB-INF/lib.

Also, in web.xml, I added:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

However, this causes Jetty to crash at startup.  What am I missing?

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading to a supported / stable / modern version of Jetty.  The documentation on eclipse.org is for Jetty 9+

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.  Jetty comes bundled with BaseX 8.5, and that is the latest version of it.

Answer (score 0):

That class doesn't exist in Jetty 8.   It halts startup because you have referenced a class that cannot be found/loaded/instantiated.

Write your own CrossOriginFilter that does what you need it to do.

Make sure it supports:

- Servlet 3.0 Based
- Async Supported Flag
- AsyncContext Aware

> Note: do not copy/paste the version from Jetty 9 (the one you attempted to use), as that also supports features present in Servlet 3.1 and will not work in Jetty 8.